# Redux toolkit: Exporting a custom hook from slice file to access actions instead of exporting all actions and then calling it again with dispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

Inside a slice file we export all the the actions from that slice. For example:

```
export const {signoutUser, updateProfile, authenticateUser, clearUserState} = sliceName.actions;
```

And then we import useDispatch and particular actions from the slice or action file based on your folder structure. For example

```
import {clearUserState} from './slice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const Component () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch(clearUserState());
//rest component body
}
```

Now instead I am exporting a custom hook from the slice file like mentioned below:

```
export const useUserDispatch = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const userDispatch = {
        signoutUser: (data) => dispatch(signoutUser(data)),
        updateProfile: (data) => dispatch(updateProfile(data)),
        authenticateUser: (data) => dispatch(authenticateUser(data)),
        clearUserState: () => dispatch(clearUserState())
      };
return {userDispatch}
    };
```

And then i can just import that hook and use like

```
const {userDispatch}=useUserDispatch();
//inside component
<button onClick={userDispatch.clearUserState()}>Dispatch Button</button>
```

I just wanted to know if it's something that's not recommended in terms of redux way of writing code or am I doing anything wrong, it works perfectly fine though.

Comment: Hi @ziyad, welcome to StackOverflow you might want to update your question useDispatch doesn't receive argument, and useUserDispatch can not be reference directly without calling

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. and the question can not be answered to pros and cons based on my experience, redux and all other open-source packages consider base common cases which people are using in the everyday app. There might be some suggestions for improvement but not best-case explanations for every app. you can just consider following and decide yourself

You can not use them as you mentioned `useUserDispatch().clearUserState()`
e.g.

```
<button onCleack={useDispatcher().clearUserState}>clear</button>
```

> 1. Hooks can be called conditionally so calling them as this level in the UI part might be conditionally canceled which is a really common case
> 2. every time this hook is called a hole new object is created for dispatchers

Also, useDispatch doesn't receive any argument and returns the nearest redux provider `store.dispatch`. see [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useDispatch.ts#L26-L33)

> Note: Redux suggests having one state for all of your apps and doesn't wrap part of your code with multiple providers.

Remember if you need this one of dispatcher (e.g. `updateProfile`) from some other part of the code, you may need to use this hook which is a waste of resources, or use it directly which shows a is a little bit of uncertainty and be not consistent from the other version (just a little is not a big case).

There are other options to handle these cases.
Remember what redux suggests for one provider, if you accept that you can also write your own dispatcher.

```
const storeDispatch = store.dispatch

// from slice file export dispatcher instead of action creator
const updateProfile = sliceName.actions.updateProfile;
export const updateProfileDispatcher = (data) => storeDispatch(updateProfile(data))
```

> This can not only be used in your component but also can be used outside of react component inside the logic
> Note: using a dispatcher outside the react is not the standard or recommended pattern and you might not want to use it.

You can also pass dispatch as the argument, something like thunk dispatcher

```
const updateProfile = dispatch => (data) => dispatch(updateProfile(data))
// or alongside of payload data
const updateProfile = (dispatch, data) => dispatch(updateProfile(data))
// also can set the default value of dispatch to store.dis
const updateProfile = (data, dispatch=storeDispatch) => dispatch(updateProfile(data))


// component
const dispatch = useDispatch()

<ProfileComponent onUpdate={updateProfile(dispatch)} />
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, I have edited the question made some mistakes in the custom hook.

Comment: I know it sounds bit confusing because of user and use words, but hear me out
useUserDispatch() is a custom hook because i need to declare const dispatch = useDispatch(); inside it.
Then I am declaring a normal js object userDispatch and then I am returning it.
Now i don't have to import actions from slice and declare useDispatch again, instead I will just import useUserDispatch and i have all the dispatch with actions at my disposal.

Comment: I kinda get it, the abstraction layer works logically fine by the way, It comes to personal preferences and optimization tips not a known bad practice as far as I know.
I mentioned some sections for optimization pitfall in the post. If there is any other thing about its usage or something let me know then I may help more properly

Comment: No that's it, that's what i wanted to know basically exporting a hook like works pretty good with the way i organise my app and if it's not violating any redux rules then it's cool

Comment: good to hear that, feel free to up vote or submit as answer :), if that was helpful for you

Comment: @Ziyad, If you come up with anything new, comment it out so I can add it up to de question for posterity